# How to create sub-domain for local host in django app?

Tags: python, django, subdomain, django-urls

How to create sub-domain in django app.
Basically i want give a sub-domain to every new register user like
http://username.127.0.0.1:8000 
so how to change the url

Answer (score 1):

You can't, if you are using Linux you may look at `/etc/hosts` file.
By example with /etc/hosts like

```
[.. stuff ..]

127.0.0.1  foo.bar www.foo.bar
127.0.0.1  egg.foo.bar bacon.foo.bar
```

Allow you to reach urls `foo.bar`, `www.foo.bar`, `egg.foo.bar` and `bacon.foo.bar` from your host.

You just have to update all `127.0.0.1` occurrences in your code / config to `foo.bar` and you'r good.

Comment: i am using windows

Comment: :( https://superuser.com/questions/525688/whats-the-windows-equivalent-of-etc-hosts

Comment: i want to use a url like **foo.127.0.0.1:800**

Comment: simple solution

Comment: I would like lot of things too, but when one of them are not possible, I try to find another way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use django-hosts for this.

You will need to set up the hosts in system32/drivers/etc/hosts.